# Robot Framework: Getting build error for missing Jar

Tags: maven-2, automated-tests, maven-plugin, robotframework

I have started learning Robot Framework (with Java & selenium lib) and was trying to write a simple test case in it. Could you please help me with it.
I have copied tools jar in the mentioned lib and also in the dependancy
But still did not work
Following is the error

**Failed to execute goal org.robotframework:robotframework-maven-plugin:1.4.6:run (default-cli) on project JavaRobot: Execution default-cli of goal org.robotframework:robotframework-maven-plugin:1.4.6:run failed: Plugin org.robotframework:robotframework-maven-plugin:1.4.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:6 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]**

Here is my POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test.Robot</groupId>
  <artifactId>JavaRobot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>JavaRobot</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>robotframework</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
   <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
   <version>1.6</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>


     <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.markusbernhardt</groupId>
      <artifactId>robotframework-selenium2library-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the exclusion , I think it will fix your problem.
Example:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.markusbernhardt</groupId>
<artifactId>robotframework-selenium2library-java</artifactId>
<version>1.4.0.7</version>
<scope>test</scope>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```